# Is possible to import Blogger stats to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, blogger

I just created a WordPress site and imported all the information from Blogger account. My question is if is possible to import the Blogger stats to Google Analytics account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. While it is by now possible to augment collected data retroactively with external data you cannot import existing data into an empty account (you could store your blogger data to a file and pipe that via the measurement protocol to Analytics, but since you cannot set a date when you send a hit all the data will show up on the same day, so that's useless for your purposes).